# Setting cookies through a CORS request

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I'm porting a client-side library for an API from JSONP to CORS.
I have set all the correct headers in the server and done all the indicated things in the client, but I have a problem regarding cookies.
That API auth method works with cookies. With JSONP, it made a GET request to the API with the API key as a parameter. Then the server set a cookie at api.io.holalabs.com (API URL), so the next time it does a call to the API the server requests the cookie and make the login.
The problem is that, although I see Set-Cookie in the headers, the cookie is not set at api.io.holalabs.com so the login fails.
These are my headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://holalabs.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-Api-Version, X-Request-Id, X-Response-Time
Connection:close
Content-Length:13
Content-MD5:RjkY1fW5i5MKifxPk+r4tg==
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 13 Apr 2012 16:06:56 GMT
Server:nginx/1.0.14
Set-Cookie:apikey.sig=DYyrzLFUfJSjsmK5crkxHQg-rxQ; path=/; httponly
X-Api-Version:1.0.0
X-Request-Id:c78b4223-1caf-42db-a99e-b075bdc10ea5
X-Response-Time:2
```

EDIT: Using cookies in a API is a horrible idea, so now we are using a header to auth the user. Issue closed!

Comment: What header did you use? `Authentication: Base ....`?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is supposedly closed, but if anyone encounters this problem and need to use cookies, here's one possible explanation and solution:

**Explanation**

The session ID is sent as a cookie, and since the request is cross-domain, it's considered a third party cookie by the browser. Several browsers will block third-party cookies, and the session is lost.

**Solution**

Generate the session ID on the client (in the browser), use Javascript sessionStorage to store the session ID then send the session ID with each request to the server.

(Details: [Javascript Cross-Domain Request With Session](https://404it.no/en/blog/javascript_cross-domain_request_with_session))